# read write csv/dataframe files

Tags: python, replit

i am trying to remove the 5th and sixth item of each line of my csv file each line is a list but when i am trying to run it i am getting a (DataFrame constructor not properly called!) error please help
[image: this is my csv file][image: this is my code]

i have tried everything i can but i cant find a simple way to remove the last 2 items of every list and then after this i want to add 2 items onto every list with a random int between diffent numbers .

Comment: Additionally, use: `import pandas as pd`.  Perhaps the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) might be of use.

Answer (score -1):

Just edit how you're reading the file

You should use

```
df = pd.read_csv('database.csv')
```

that's why you are getting that error.

Answer (score -1):

You reading the file incorrectly

```
df = pd.DataFrame() is for creating a new dataframe.
```

You should use

```
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
```

Comment: but when i do that i get this error (Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    new_df=df.drop(df.iloc[-1,:],axis=1)
  File "/home/runner/DarkgreenHardtofindNlp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5388, in drop
    return super().drop(
  File "/home/runner/DarkgreenHardtofindNlp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 6975, in drop
    raise KeyError(f"{list(labels[mask])} not found in axis")
KeyError: '[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4] not found in axis')

Comment: They are the further errors so upto 10 line your code is fine.